# kubernetes custom resource definition required field

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

I am trying to write a kubernetes crd validation schema. I have an array (vc) of structures and one of the fields in those structures is required (`name` field).

I tried looking through various examples but it doesn't generate error when `name` is not there. Any suggestions what is wrong ?

```
vc:
  type: array
  items:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      address:
        type: string
    required:
    - name
```

Comment: Is other validations for CRD working for you? I mean, other required fields? And, what is your kubernetes version?

Answer (score 5):

If you are on v1.8, you will need to enable the `CustomResourceValidation` feature gate for using the validation feature. This can be done by using the following flag on kube-apiserver:

```
--feature-gates=CustomResourceValidation=true
```

Here is an example of it working (I tested this on v1.12, but this should work on earlier versions as well):

The CRD:

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: foos.stable.example.com
spec:
  group: stable.example.com
  versions:
    - name: v1
      served: true
      storage: true
  version: v1
  scope: Namespaced
  names:
    plural: foos
    singular: foo
    kind: Foo
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        spec:
          properties:
            vc:
              type: array
              items:
                type: object
                properties:
                  name:
                    type: string
                  address:
                    type: string
                required:
                - name
```

The custom resource:

```
apiVersion: "stable.example.com/v1"
kind: Foo
metadata:
  name: new-foo
spec:
  vc:
  - address: "bar"
```

1. Create the CRD.

`kubectl create -f crd.yaml`
`customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/foos.stable.example.com created`

2. Get the CRD and check if the validation field exists in the output. If it doesn't, you probably don't have the feature gate turned on.

`kubectl get crd foos.stable.example.com -oyaml`

3. Try to create the custom resource. This should fail with:

`kubectl create -f cr-validation.yaml`

`The Foo "new-foo" is invalid: []: Invalid value: map[string]interface {}{"metadata":map[string]interface {}{"creationTimestamp":"2018-11-18T19:45:23Z", "generation":1, "uid":"7d7f8f0b-eb6a-11e8-b861-54e1ad9de0be", "name":"new-foo", "namespace":"default"}, "spec":map[string]interface {}{"vc":[]interface {}{map[string]interface {}{"address":"bar"}}}, "apiVersion":"stable.example.com/v1", "kind":"Foo"}: validation failure list:
spec.vc.name in body is required`

Comment: under `vc` if the `name` and `address` has to be set in the custom resource object, how will it look like ? like this: ?
```
vc:
  - name: "some name"
  - address: "bar"
```